# SQLAlchemy - Parent child relationship in the same table

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I want to have a parent child relationship in the same table. Below is what I have, and it isn't working. By "not working", I meant that when I call `.children` on some `Item` object, it gives me `[]`. What is the error in my code and how to do it correctly? Thanks.

```
parents_children = Table('parents_children', Base.metadata,
                         Column('parent_id', bigint, ForeignKey('items.id', name='a'), primary_key=True),
                         Column('child_id', bigint, ForeignKey('items.id', name='b'), primary_key=True)
                         )

class Item(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'items'
    id = Column(bigint, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(types.String(80), default="")
    display_name = Column(types.String(80), default="")
    version = Column(types.String(80), default="")
    discriminator = Column(item_tag_enum, nullable=False)
    children = relationship('Item',
                            secondary=parents_children,
                            primaryjoin=id == parents_children.c.parent_id,
                            secondaryjoin=id == parents_children.c.child_id,
                            backref='parents')
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_on' : discriminator}

 # Item subclasses omitted because that's irrelevant to the question.
```

Comment: That's weird, your code looks pretty ok. Can you include the code for adding child items? And have you checked that when you add children then changes are committed to the database? I think it's probably just transaction weirdness and not a problem with the item class itself

Comment: @Sheena, I have this method which I call from elsewhere: https://www.refheap.com/paste/5893.

Comment: I think I understood what's wrong. The insert statement object is created but never executed. Is there a way to execute it using a session object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is an easier way... (this is how I do it)

```
def adopt(parent_id,child_id):
    parent = DBSession.query(Item).get(parent_id)
    child  = DBSession.query(Item).get(child_id)
    parent.children.append(child)
```

Comment: That's certainly nicer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, problem solved.

I was creating an insert statement object but not executing it.

What I had:

```
def adopt(parent_id, child_id):
    print('{} adopts {}'.format(parent_id, child_id))
    parents_children.insert(values=dict(parent_id=parent_id, child_id=child_id))
```

What I now have:

```
def adopt(parent_id, child_id):
    print('{} adopts {}'.format(parent_id, child_id))
    i = parents_children.insert(values=dict(parent_id=parent_id, child_id=child_id))
    conn = engine.connect()
    conn.execute(i)
```

Now everything works as expected.

So the problem was somewhere else than the snippet I included in the original post. Please feel free to delete the question.